# promise await timeout exceeded

Tags: node.js, async-await, nock

i got this following code inside a async function.
when i am calling the function i am getting stuck after the await statement.
i already checked my nock address for http req mocking and it is the same as in the request.

```
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            let req = http.request(reqUrl, function (res) {
                console.info('Start http GET request');
                var responseBody = '';
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                // Read the response body
                res.on('data', function (data) {
                    responseBody = data;
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                    console.info('feature toggle response code ' + res.statusCode);
                    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                        if (responseBody.trim() != '') {
                            if (responseBody === 'true') {
                                console.info('feature toggle is on');
                                self.evolveData.getByAttribute = self.evolveData.getByAttributeLimited;
                            } else {
                                console.info('feature toggle is off');
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        printErrorMessage('fail message', res, responseBody);
                        self.context.fail(responseBody);
                    }
                    resolve();
                });
                req.on('error', function () {
                    self.context.fail(responseBody);
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: For starters, move the `req.on('error', ...)` outside of the `http.request()` callback.  You may be getting an error occurring early before you get a chance to hook up the error handler.  That would mean you have an error condition, but never get to call `resolve()` or `reject()`.

Comment: Also you need to change `responseBody = data;` to `responseBody += data;` because you can get more than one `data` event and you presumably want to accumulate the data.

Comment: moved it and changed the responseBody, now i am getting error 'req' is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `http.request()`, you have to call `req.end()` to actually initiate the request and send it.  Note, if you switch to `http.get()`, then you don't have to call `req.end()` because `http.get()` does it for you.

Here's a stand-alone program that demonstrates:

```
const http = require('http');

async function run() {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        let req = http.request("http://www.google.com", function (res) {
            console.log('Start http GET request');
            var responseBody = '';
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            // Read the response body
            res.on('data', function (data) {
                responseBody += data;
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                console.info('feature toggle response code ' + res.statusCode);
                if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log("got 200 response")
                }
                resolve();
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function () {
            console.log("error");
            resolve();
        });
        req.end();               // <=== You were missing this
    });
    console.log("after await");
}

run();
```

If you remove the `req.end()` so it's missing like it is in your code, you get the same thing.  The promise never resolves because the request is never sent.

---

Also, for completeness, notice that the `req.on('error', ...)` needs to be up at a higher level (outside the `http.request()` callback) so you can get errors that might occur before the callback is called or in cases where the callback is not called because of the error.

---

FYI, a couple doc references:

From the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) for `http.request()`:

> With http.request() one must always call `req.end()` to signify the end
>   of the request - even if there is no data being written to the request
>   body.

From the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) for `http.get()`:

> The only difference between this method and `http.request()` is that it
>   sets the method to GET and calls `req.end()` automatically.

Comment: @Dev93 - Did this fix it for you?

Comment: never mind, had a problem in my mocking, thanks for your help!